# Trying to use SUBSTR(XMLCAST(XMLGROUP for dates and dec getting error

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to use the following with Date of Decimal type data

```
 SUBSTR(XMLCAST(XMLGROUP(',' || name AS a
                      ORDER BY name)
             AS VARCHAR(60)), 2) AS Names,
```

Of course the varchar works for the right set of data but for dates and decimals I cannot get it to work

```
SUBSTR(XMLCAST(XMLGROUP(',' || Trim(Part_Num) AS a ORDER BY ORD_NUM) AS VARCHAR(250)), 2) AS Part_Num
```

Thoughts on what a decimal or date should look like?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are asking. Can you explain in English (as opposed to SQL or XML) what you are trying to achieve, and provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: I am using this substr to combine all the information associated to the order number in a single comma separated cell

Example say I have 10 line items same quote number single part per line item, using this substr I get a single line item and all parts combined separated by comma in my output.

I am looking to do the same for some date fields and QTY fields

Comment: You can simply use listagg function to get comma seperated values

Comment: I cannot use it with DB2 9.5 for some reason this one works though

Comment: And for dates you need to first fetch whaeter you want from date n do aggregation,  like u want year then year(yourdate) then aggregation